# Android app session - session remains even if I uninstall then reinstall app

Tags: android, cordova, session, cordova-plugins, cordova-5.0.0

I have a Cordova app built in version 5 that I am testing on my Android device - it has a login system that uses an API to authenticate a username & password.

It has logged in but when I uninstall the app then re-install it the app still is logged in??!

I have even tried to empty the cache for the app but I am always still logged into the same account - can anyone suggest what I am doing?

Any advice appreciated.

-- update --
The app has a login screen (username/password) which basically connects to an external API  - this API queries a database which returns the account details & sets a token which is used for subsequent requests to retrieve the same user account.

The app doesn't have any logout functionality (it should do really) but it should logout once the app has been re-installed.. really odd.

I've tried the 'Clear Data' and 'Clear Cache' options within the App settings but the same problem persists.

-- Update --
This is the js file that appears to do all the logic with the storage (I am not quite sure how this works.. it was developed by a different group of developers)

https://gist.github.com/gkimpson/f234ac2f33f9455e7291

Comment: What is the flow of authentication? And could you try **Clear Data** and see what happens?

Comment: Still happens after using all the Clear Data & Clear Cache options.. odd

Comment: I think you should use localStorage for persistence. iOS was not very good with Cookies, they might have fixed it but older ones might have their cookies cleared with exiting the app. And I think this has to do with webviews, which involves Android browser; so could you try clearing the cookies of your Android's browser and the re-check your application?

Comment: Tried opening my default browser on my phone (chrome) and clearing all the 'private data' and uninstalling & re-installing the app but with no joy.

Comment: Does your Android have the browser named **Internet**? The one which used to come with every Android, as far as I know.

Comment: I am using the OnePlusOne Android device and I just checked the apps and this doesn't appear to have the "Internet" application installed (Chrome appears to be the only browser installed and is the default)

Comment: Oh, then I am not sure. Because my Android's built in browser shares the sessions with my application too. But like I said above, iOS might have issues with cookies, so implement `localStorage` instead.

Comment: @Zabs did you find any solution for this.